# Re-evaluate "canActivate" when condition changes without navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular 4 application with some route guarded by this class:

```
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        return this.userService.isAdministrator();
    }
}
```

This allows a route to be protected if the user is an administrator. It works very well but there is a logout functionality in the `UserService` that emits on an `Observable` allowing the different UI components to be refreshed.

What I would like is to be able, somehow, to subscribe to this `Observable` in the guard and then re-evaluate it when the logout event fires in order to see if the current route can still be activated. The aim behind this is to be able to redirect the user to the homepage if he logs out while still on an admin page.

Comment: Does the logout change the url at all?

Comment: Nop, it justs emits on an observable.

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1: Create a directive which you could add at the highest level(probable to your app.component). Within this directive, subscribe to your observable. Within you subscribe method, use the activateRoute.snapshot to check your current path. Redirect if necessary.

2: Create a directive which you could add at the highest level(probable to your app.component). Within this directive, subscribe to your observable and refresh the page in your subscribe.

3: A guard is basically nothing else than a service. You could simply subscribe to the canActivate method.

Comment: Yeah, that was the plan B, I was just hoping that it could be done from within the guard. Maybe it's not.

Comment: What about again creating a directive and refreshing the page?

Comment: Then, I can simply refresh the page when a logout is performed and that's it. As I said, I was just hoping a cleaner method.

Comment: Check my third option